# Java:: How to use regex in file no-line-break over 800 meg

Tags: java, regex, string

If I have data over 800 meg, data is no break line .
I will work with regex example Ex.

```
String.replaceAll("([a-z][a-z][.?!]+) ?([A-Z][a-z]+ )", "$1\r\n$2");
```

or others.

please guide me what should I do for use regex in file size case.

Comment: Q: Have to tried it? Definitely curious ;)

Comment: You definitely don't want to use a regex for that!

Comment: 800 meg is too large to realistically be held in memory is a String. You should use a command line tool that can process the file as a stream, like `sed`

Comment: for stream , i tried to use regex and I dont have way to do, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use a regex for such a size.

If you don't have any of the classical Unix tools (sed, perl, awk) at your disposal to help, have a look at Guava's [CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html): read your file in a byte array, convert that to a String, use CharMatcher to find anything of interest, if yes write a modified array.

And, of course, do not write inline but in *another* file, and rename to the original if you have successfully performed your transformations.

For your punctuation needs, for instance, you can use a `CharMatcher.anyOf("?!.")`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have enough ram to load the data in memory i cant see why it cant be done. i think the limiting value would be the architecture if its a 32bit system 64 can handle a larger amount of addressing and that's when it will use its 4gb ~ limit.

You will also need to set you java vm to a lot bigger than the default vm max memory setting.
eg

```
java -Xmx1g myprogram
```

I still wouldnt reccoment it.
isnt there a way you could split the file first.
find a common delimeter.
Thanks